# How to pass GET form data to Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, routes

I have a form

```
<form action="./search" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Job Title" />
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Find Jobs</button>
         </div>
</form>
```

If I enter "akron" in the form and submit and pass it to this next method it returns "Cannot GET /search?keyword=akron"

```
router.get('/search/:keyword', function(req, res) {
   res.send('hello ' + req.params.keyword + '!');
})
```

But if I type http://localhost:3000/search/akron it will return the "hello akron!"

What is the correct way to pass the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
action="/search"
```

The "./blah" syntax with dot in front is for files.

Also change to

```
router.get("/search"  //...
```

and use req.query

Comment: Just tested it. That wasnt the problem. I'm still getting the same result without the ".".

Comment: Thanks! the req.query worked and the "." was causing a problem too.

Comment: Why would the `.` cause a problem?